# Javascript per second calculation

Tags: javascript, math

I am currently wracking my brain to work out what should probably be a relatively simple per second calculation. I have a loading bar increase and at the end of that, it adds 1 to the total. The loading bar consists of:

```
wId = setInterval(worker_identify_call, wIdSpeed);
```

and

```
function worker_identify_call(){
    worker_identify_amount++;
    wElem.style.width = worker_identify_amount + '%';
}
```

wIdSpeed = 250.

I am trying to calculate how long, in seconds, it will take to reach the top of the loading bar (100%).

I currently have `((1000/wIdSpeed).toFixed(2))` but that just calculates how long a cycle of `setInterval` takes.

[CodePen with example here.](https://codepen.io/kaostic/pen/qBPbbVR?editors=1111)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in idiot. For anyone that wants to find this in the future, it would be:

```
(((wIdSpeed/1000)*100).toFixed(2));
```

Where wIdSpeed is the speed of your interval.

Comment: Why not just:

`wIdSpeed / 10` ?

Comment: ... because that would have been far too simple. Now I feel doubly stupid - I'll blame it for being late.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recalculate after every cycle you have to move `workerString();` to inside the function that loops.

As for the math, you need to get the remaining `(100 - worker_identify_amount)` and check how many things it's adding per second and figure out the result from that.

Comment: I think I figured it out and it was as simple as multiplying the calculation by 100. Yes, I feel dumb. 

`(((wIdSpeed/1000)*100).toFixed(2));`